# FullCalendar, Time Zone Issues. Showing events at GMT +8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, fullcalendar

I have been facing this problem where full calendar shows my event at a time 8 hours later than the event data.
I figured that it is due to my timezone.

This is my trace message

```
Started GET "/events?custom_param1=something&custom_param2=somethingelse&  start=1351958400&end=1352563200&   authenticity_token=XEXpcBRnQuEivJ2NWjR2+OZ+Uscypalxx+hqGTIiwZA=&_=1352086291522" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-05 11:31:31 +0800
Processing by EventsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"custom_param1"=>"something", "custom_param2"=>"somethingelse", "start"=>"1351958400", "end"=>"1352563200", "authenticity_token"=>"XEXpcBRnQuEivJ2NWjR2 OZ Uscypalxx hqGTIiwZA=", "_"=>"1352086291522"}
  Event Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE (starts_at > '2012-11-04T00:00:00+08:00') AND (ends_at < '2012-11-11T00:00:00+08:00')
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 8.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

The problem here being the start time in Unix is Sat, 03 Nov 2012 16:00:00 GMT when I had set it to be 04 Nov 2012 0.00.00.

Here are my codes

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :before, lambda {|end_time| {:conditions => ["ends_at < ?",   Event.format_date(end_time)] }}
  scope :after, lambda {|start_time| {:conditions => ["starts_at > ?", Event.format_date(start_time)] }}
  def as_json(options = {})
    {
      :id => self.id,
      :title => self.title,
      :description => self.description || "",
      :start => starts_at.rfc822,
      :end => ends_at.rfc822,
      :allDay => false,
      :recurring => false,
      :url => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.event_path(id),
      #:color => "red"
    }

  end

  def self.format_date(date_time)
    Time.at(date_time.to_i).to_time.iso8601
  end
end
```

changing ignoreTimeZone to true didn't work for me either.
So I would appreciate if someone could help me with it.

Maybe something along the lines of parsing time?

Comment: can use `Date.getTimezoneOffset()` in javascript to return minutes difference of user from UTC/GMT https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset Where within your app you want to make adjustments isn't clear...server vs client

Comment: Probably the server side. I want the event time I have set to correspond with what I see on the calendar but right now my events are showing at a time 8 hours later.

Comment: API option `ignoreTimezone` is default to true, so likely would solve your issues http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/ignoreTimezone/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing a UNIX time value, it may be in seconds or milliseconds UTC from the epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z). To get a local javascript date object set to the same time in the client's local timezone, pass the UTC time value directly to the [Date constructor](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2).

e.g.

```
// if timeValue is milliseconds
var localDate = new Date(timeValue);

// if timeValue is in seconds
var localDate = new Date(timeValue * 1000);
```

e.g.

```
// For timeValue in milliseconds
new Date(1352090840000); // 2012-11-05T04:47:20Z
```

To send back local times as UTC milliseconds since the epoch, do the reverse:

```
var utcTimeValue = localDate.getTime();
```

The [time value](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1) returned by [`getTime`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.9) is UTC milliseconds since epoch.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've moved on to something else so I didn't get to try this out.
For anyone else who might be interested.
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=750

Comment: I'll get back to you when I get back to doing this.